# Why do I see different versions of bash history for the same user

Tags: bash, command-history

I ssh into my servers using root.  Sometimes when I scroll back in my history, I see a history from an earlier session, but not the last session.  Why does this happen with the same user account?  Is it related to the tty I am using? Bash 4

Answer (score 4):

Every time you close a shell the contents of the history for that particular shell overwrites the history file that was written by previous ones.

The contents of a shell's history is stored in this file `$HOME/.bash_history`. It's a plain text file so you can check it out. There are numerous options to history that you can set to augment it's behavior. Take a look at the [bash man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-History-Facilities). Most of them are named `hist*` or `HIST*`. Just search for them.

In particular, `shopt -s histappend` makes bash append the current session's history to the history file instead of overwriting the history file.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons this could happen.

First off, if the last session is still active, it would not have saved it's history to the history file unless the `history -a` (append new history) or `history -w` (over-write history) command was executed from the shell.

In addition, if the shell terminated abnormally, such as due to a `kill -9`, which should only ever be used as a last resort, that would prevent it from saving the history.

Another issue I've seen is using the `script` command, although I suspect that's just order-of-operations and my own projections/wishful thinking.  The new shell session run by `script` doesn't have the newest history because it re-reads the file.  Also, after existing `script`, the parent shell doesn't update with the history created there.  Using the `history` command, this should be easy to fix.